# What do the numbers represent in an AssociationTypeMismatch error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, rails-activerecord

I got the following while attempting an assignment using the Rails console.

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: PurchaseOrder(#70303731156560) expected, got PurchaseOrder(#70303775861760)
```

What does `#70303731156560` and `#70303775861760` represent?

Comment: I believe those are class.object_id's

Answer (score 0):

When `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` error occurs, those numbers after the class names refer to the different versions of the class. This error occurs when two different versions of the model have been loaded.

To solve this problem, you could use `reload!` in the console. Or, re-starting the console should fix it.